# Pure gui window in OpenCV has black rectangle and crops text at bottom

Tags: python, opencv

For my application I want one gui window to let the user adjust some values, and the other window will show the streaming video. Code is something like this:

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("GUI")
cv2.createTrackbar("Spanky", "GUI", 100,200, lambda x: x)
cv2.createTrackbar("Alfalfa", "GUI", 11, 22, lambda x: x)
```

I'm expecting a nice gui window, but end up with half black rectangle, with the gui elements at the bottom, and some text that is cropped off below those:

[image: pic showing problem with rectangle and cropping]

How can I get rid of that black rectangle, and (less importantly) get it so that text at the bottom is not cropped?

I am in OpenCV 4.1, Python 3.6, Windows 10.

Comment: I don't use Windows and I don't have black rectangle. As I know some players use black rectangle to inform system (system's driver) where it has to display video's stream.

Comment: @furas I updated question to indicate I'm in Windows.

Comment: How can I set its height to zero I wonder? On phone will research later ..

Comment: as for black rectangle - you may try to draw image with grey color. Probably if you draw image with zero height then it can make it smaller. As for cropped text - it looks like you have set bigger font in system and program didn't expect it. You can always use other GUI framework - Tkinter, wxPython, PyQt - and create all window from scratch. There are example with [tkinter], wxPython, PyGame]9https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2)

Comment: [example with tkinter, wxPython, PyGame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2)